# Multiple div with equal width in a container

Tags: css

I am trying to place multiple divs with same width inside a container in same row as below

```
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    + ++++++++ ++++++++ ++++++++ +
    + +      + +      + +      + +
    + + box1 + + box2 + + box3 + +
    + +      + +      + +      + +
    + ++++++++ ++++++++ ++++++++ +
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

The container has
width:100%;
I was successful to place 3 divs in same row.
float: left;
display: inline-block;
but I couldn't fix the same width for the multiple divs.

Comment: Please post your code, preferably in a jsfiddle

Comment: First read faq and about us .. those two are important section will help you understand how this site works and how to post a question

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
.inner-boxes {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 1.5%;
}
```

To make each box a third of the width of the container.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap a div inside another div.

code:

```
     div { border: 2px solid red; } 
     div.wrapper { 
     border: 2px solid blue;
     display: inline-block;
```

}

Html Code:

```
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="wrap">
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 83px;">This is good</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Refer:
[how to make a div to wrap two float divs inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844207/how-to-make-a-div-to-wrap-two-float-divs-inside),

[CSS word-wrapping in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502500/css-word-wrapping-in-div),

[How to wrap divs like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879379/how-to-wrap-divs-like-this)

Answer (score 0):

Use display table property

```css
.tbl {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.tbl .row {
  display: table-row;
}

.tbl .row div {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl">
  <div class="row">
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div>TEST</div>
    <div>TEST</div>
  </div>
</div>
```